# How to remove windows prompt when writing on a samba share?

Tags: permissions, raspberry-pi, samba, raspbian

I have configured a samba share on my rasbpberry external hdd.

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   logging = file
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   server role = standalone server
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   usershare allow guests = yes

[share]
    comment = Share Directory
    path = /media/usbhdd1/Shared/
    browseable = Yes
    writeable = Yes
    only guest = no
    create mask = 0644
    directory mask = 0755
    public = yes
    force user = pi
```

When writing files from Windows, I get an access denied prompt but  it lets me "confirm" the action and ends up writing the file.

```
ls -ld /media/usbhdd1 /media/usbhdd1/Shared

drwxr-xr-x 4 pi pi 4096 Jan 27 13:18 /media/usbhdd1/
drwxr-xr-x 3 pi pi 4096 Jan 27 14:05 /media/usbhdd1/Shared/
```

```
mount | grep /media/usbhdd1

/dev/sda on /media/usbhdd1 type ext4 (rw,relatime)
```

Am I missing something? I don't think this is how it should behave.

Thank you.

Comment: Btw I've seen several guides where people do create mask and directory mask 0777 but that doesn't sound right to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the `create mask` and `directory mask` lines with,

```
force create mode = 0644
force directory mode = 0755
```

Because you were using mask entries you've restricted the file permissions on the disk a little too much. These two instructions I've offered set the mode rather then modify it.

The permissions should work fine because you've got `force user = pi`. Without that you'd probably want permission modes 0666 and 0777 respectively.