# How to send files from windows 10 to virtualbox using samba?

Tags: linux

I am trying to send a file from my windows 10 host machine to my virtual machine using samba and I am not allowed to use virtualBox share. How would I be able to do that?

Comment: Very related - [How to remove windows prompt when writing on a samba share?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/733332/100397)

Comment: Mind you, the obvious way is to use the virtual box share. So much easier